# Add row in list view in android

Tags: android

I have a list view and i want to add 4 rows in the list view and each row contains progress bar and start button. For this purpose i have created another layout for row which contains progress bar and button.
Now in my main activity i am writing the code but listview is not displaying.

```
ArrayAdapter adapter = new Arrayadaper(this, R.layout.row);

ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have another answer. after you could do this you will find it impossible to put a button in a row of ListView unfortunately and there is no solution for that. if you put a button you can not click on the row of ListView. :(